# How do I move window buttons to the right on Ubuntu 20?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, titlebar, window-buttons

After upgrade to Ubuntu 20, my window buttons moved again to the left and I don't know how change it in this version of distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Install GNOME Tweaks:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Run the program, the setting for titlebar buttons placement is under *Window Titlebars*.

Note: You'll need to enable the universe repository if it's not enabled already:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bit embarrassed :) because i've looked for it option in "Widnow" tab (ad in Ubuntu 18)

Comment: I have the same problem. If I set the option to right in tweaks, the buttons move in the tweaks window but all other windows still have the buttons on the left. I have reset dconf settings, no change.What else can I try?